# Turf booleanPointInPolygon always returns false

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I want to check if a point is in a polygon:

```
if (turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, poly_coordinates)) {
    console.log("INSIDE");
} else {
    console.log("OUTSIDE");
}
```

JSON.stringify(console.log(pt)) displays:

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[2.1362996,41.391026000000004]}}
```

JSON.stringify(console.log(poly_coordinates)) displays:

```
[[[2.1666008868967594,41.420742231455876],[2.1423966327457435,41.39486355482066],[2.159906093195218,41.38185595077573],[2.1666008868967594,41.420742231455876]]]
```

**NOTE: Everything is in longitude,latitude format.**

Why is it booleanPointInPolygon returning false? This particular case is just an example point and an example polygon which might be outside the polygon. However, it doesn't matter if the polygon contains the entire world, booleanPointInPolygon still returns false for any point.

Comment: It'll be much easier to diagnose if you include example data.

Comment: @SteveBennett I added the JSON for the list of points (ranked_racks) and another for the output of a drawn polygon (zone). Thanks!

Comment: @SteveBennett I simplified the question for clarity. Hopefully, everything is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's your code, then the problem is that `poly_coordinates` is not a polygon, it's just the coordinates part of one.

You should have something like:

```js
const poly = { type: 'Polygon', coordinates: poly_coordinates }
turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, poly)
```

Comment: That solved it. Nevertheless, I want to understand why my attempt did not work. My coordinates for the polygon have exactly the same format as the example in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon) of `booleanPointInPolygon`.

Comment: In that example, the array is first being passed to `turf.polygon()` which does the same thing as I added.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can also use this

```js
var pt = turf.point([1, 1]);
var poly = turf.polygon([
    [
        [-1, -1],
        [-1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [-1, -1]
    ]
]);

var inside = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(pt, poly);
```